# Magento and Worldpay USA

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, worldpay

I have Magento 1.7 version and am trying to integrate with Worldpay USA and I am using [this extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/worldpay-extension.html).

The problem is, I can't find where to get an `installation ID` and other data required by the  extension.

I tried looking at the documentation and various installation guides, which all point me to installation page. But in my merchant interface there is no such menu item.

Maybe it is different for WorldPay USA?

Comment: So you have installed the extension but do not how to use it, haven't you? Please, correct me if I am misunderstood.

Comment: Yes, I've installed the extension. There is no clear guide how to setup it to work with WorldPay.us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We didn't find any extension which works with WorldPay **USA**. Decided to move to Authorize.net and Paypal.

Answer (score 0):

Installation ID should be entered only for Business type accounts only and it is issued by WorldPay Support Team.

For more information, visit this [tutorial](http://jbiwebdesign.co.uk/resources/worldpay-payment-gateway-integration/) and [Magento Wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/payment-gateways-worldpay)

Does this solve your question? If not, do not hesitate to ask. Hope that helps.